# Create a person with alfresco RESTApi using xmlhttprequest

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, alfresco, alfresco-share

So I'm creating a custom share page for alfresco and I want to create a person using javascript thanks to the [REST API](https://api-explorer.alfresco.com/api-explorer/#!/people/createPerson) (You will find all the doc about the api and why I shaped my var this way here) so I wrote this code which contains a xmlhttprequest to post the data :

```
var boby = "{ \"id\": \"bob\",\"firstName\": \"Bob\", \"lastName\": \"LeBricoleur\", \"email\": \"bob@lebricoleur.com\", \"telephone\": \"6666666666\", \"enabled\": true,\"emailNotificationsEnabled\": true, \"password\": \"bob\" }";
                        console.log(boby);
                        function loadDoc() {
                            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                              document.getElementById("creatingperson").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                            }
                            };
                            xhttp.open("POST", 'http://localhost:8081/share/proxy/alfresco-api/-default-/public/alfresco/versions/1/people', true);
                            xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");    //curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=' -d '[...]
                            xhttp.send(boby);
                        }
```

Ok so this doesn't give me anything.. Not even an error message. At first I thought it was because of my whole code so I created the variable boby that I would send to the server to simplify the debug but I still don't know where the error comes from.

Is it a problem from my code ? From my way of using the api ? From alfresco share itself ? If you can help me thanks a lot !

P.S : I wrote a code to list people (instead of creating one) which works using the same url if that can help

---

[EDIT]

I've found another way to make my request and it works but I don't know why.. here is the code :

```
var createperson = "{ \"id\": \"" + document.getElementById('login').value + "\",\"firstName\": \"" + document.getElementById('firstName').value + "\", \"lastName\": \"" + document.getElementById('lastName').value + "\", \"email\": \"" + document.getElementById('mail').value + "\", \"telephone\": \"" + document.getElementById('telephone').value + "\", \"enabled\": true,\"emailNotificationsEnabled\": true, \"password\": \"" + document.getElementById('pwd2').value + "\" }";
                        console.log(createperson);
                            var url = "http://localhost:8080/alfresco/api/-default-/public/alfresco/versions/1/people";
                            var method = "POST";
                            var async = true;
                            //var postData = "{ \"id\": \"bob\",\"firstName\": \"Bob\", \"lastName\": \"LeBricoleur\", \"email\": \"bob@lebricoleur.com\", \"telephone\": \"6666666666\", \"enabled\": true,\"emailNotificationsEnabled\": true, \"password\": \"bob\" }";

                            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
                            request.onload = function () {
                               var status = request.status; // HTTP response status, e.g., 201 for "201 OK"
                               var data = request.responseText; // Returned data, e.g., an HTML document.
                                console.log("status :");
                                console.log(status);
                                console.log("data :");
                                console.log(data);
                            }

                            request.open(method, url, async);
                            request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                            request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=");
                            request.send(createperson);
```

Moreover when I try to use this type of request to list the people (just to use the method everywhere) it doesn't work.. here is a part of what I wrote to list people :

```
var url = "http://192.168.1.103:8080/alfresco/api/-default-/public/alfresco/versions/1/people";
         var method = "GET";
         var async = true;
         var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
         request.onload = function () {
               var status = request.status; // HTTP response status, e.g., 201 for "201 OK"
           objet = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
               console.log("status :");
               console.log(status);
               console.log("data :");
               console.log(objet);
         }

         request.open(method, url, async); //, "admin", "admin");
         request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
         request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=");
```

So if anyone knows why it worked for creating someone and why it doesn't for listing thank you for your answer !

Comment: Why don't you recreate the API request in question using some kind of REST client and make sure it work there? That way, you'll know for sure that part works.

Comment: Which version of alfresco you are using?

Comment: @Lista this part works I've done it thanks to Postman and I get a good result

Comment: @KrutikJayswal I'm using _Community - 5.2.0 (r135134-b14)_

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this information could be useful. Take a look.

https://community.alfresco.com/community/ecm/blog/2017/04/18/v1-rest-api-part-10-people

Regards,

Comment: Yes thanks ! Even though it doesn't clearly says how to code it helped me to know what the response looked like and if I'm able to make a request to the server !

Answer (score 1):

Basically there can be 2 issues.

1.This api is only supported in alfresco version 5.2 and letter and your version should be below 5.2.
2.There was some CSRF token issue in xhr call.Can be solved by adding csrf token.For this function code is as below.

```
function loadDoc() {
                            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(demo) {console.log(demo.error);
                            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                              console.log(this);
                            }
                            };
                            xhttp.open("POST", 'http://localhost:8081/share/proxy/alfresco-api/-default-/public/alfresco/versions/1/people', true);
                            xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                            xhttp.setRequestHeader(Alfresco.util.CSRFPolicy.getHeader(), Alfresco.util.CSRFPolicy.getToken());//CSRF Token
                            xhttp.send(boby);
                        }
```

Comment: I've changed the way I was making the request and now it works, I don't have a clue why but it does work. I will update my original post to let you see the new code. But when I try to use the same method to, this time, list people it doesn't work..

Comment: For list people , request method is get and not post.

Comment: I'm sorry, translation error, when I said method I meant type of http request as you can see above, I used GET

Comment: Basically , previously you were using share proxy aithentication , which was have CSRF enable, so alfresco share will block your call.In the edited code, you are using alfresco server, in which you are doing authentication using base64 mechanism.This is the reason behind it works.